# CachingConnnectionFactory, JMSTemplate and MQJMS2019

Tags: java, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have developed a highly-concurrent application where 15 automated jobs need to connect to 15 different Websphere MQ (one per job) every 10 minutes. I'm using `CCF` along with `JMSTemplate` for better performance and caching benefits. I know that `CachingConnectionFactory` class has another important benefit that it automatically set `reconnectOnException = true`, but still whenever WMQ server is restarted, the application is not able to re-establish the connection with it once it is up becuase of the cached connection which are already broken and producing error MQJMS2009. I would like to know if there is an explicit way to re-establish the connection with `CCF`.

Comment: Can you check this technote http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21508357 for different reconnect options.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Spring JavaDoc, if reconnectOnException is set then a JMS ExceptionListener will be registered on the underlying Connection and when the ExceptionListener catches an exception then it will reset the connection.  The connection will be renewed the next time it is accessed.

The CachingConnectionFactory class has a resetConnection() method which provides you an explicit way of resetting the connection as per your question.

However, as Umamahesh mentioned in his comment you might wish to investigate the automatic client reconnect feature that is offered by WebSphere MQ itself.  This feature will attempt to catch connection errors and transparently reconnect to a queue manager without throwing an exception up to the Spring layer.  It is most commonly used in HA environments (in conjunction with a list of queue managers in a connection name list or CCDT) but it also works well for abnormal termination of a single queue manager.

The simplest way to test this would be to enable automatic reconnect on your connection factory using:

```
ConnectionFactory.setClientReconnectOptions( WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT );
```

You can read more about using client reconnect in JMS here:  https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032520_.htm?lang=en

If you decide to use automatic reconnect then there are some consequences of the transparent reconnect that you should be aware of - particularly if you are: delivering messages under transaction control; browsing a queue; or using temporary dynamic queues.  These consequences are documented in detail in the ***Recovery of an automatically reconnected client*** section of this topic: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q018380_.htm?lang=en

Note that MQ's automatic reconnect feature is designed to work in the event of a queue manager failure (or a planned switch over), so to test it you will need to either end the queue manager with "endmqm -r", or emulate a failure by killing the queue manager / channel (amqrmppa) processes.